# How to add a range dropdown using either bootstrap or jquery UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap

How to add the html component as shown in the attached image to a page.

[image: priority]

Comment: There is `<input type="number">`, it's maybe what you want. [demo](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_type_number)

Comment: did you ever Google It? http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-slider/

Comment: @balexandre do u see a slider in the image?

Comment: what image are you talking about???

Answer (score 2):

In this case you are looking for a "spinner", and jQuery UI has that. When you look here: http://jqueryui.com/spinner/ you can see different ways of using the spinner.

For bootstrap you could use this component for bootstrap: http://www.virtuosoft.eu/code/bootstrap-touchspin/

Also the HTML5 input type "Number" as in the comment of Rick Lancee could be used for this goal.